# Which type of query will be faster?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'll be fetching more than 50k records and match the records with another table. The query is like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT *,
(SELECT TOP 1 t2.depart FROM table2 t2 WHERE t1.tripId = t2.tripID ORDER BY t2.tripID DESC) AS Depart,
(SELECT TOP 1 t2.arrival FROM table2 t2 WHERE t1.tripId = t2.tripID ORDER BY t2.tripID DESC) AS arrival
 FROM table1 t1) x
WHERE x.Depart IS NOT NULL AND x.arrival IS NULL;
```

In the above query, I'm sub querying the original one and applying where condition. I'll be fetching more than 50k records so is this approach faster or the below one:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
WHERE 
(SELECT TOP 1 t2.depart FROM table2 t2 WHERE t1.tripId = t2.tripID ORDER BY t2.tripID DESC) IS NOT NULL 
AND
(SELECT TOP 1 t2.arrival FROM table2 t2 WHERE t1.tripId = t2.tripID ORDER BY t2.tripID DESC) 
IS NULL;
```

Any suggestions or improvements are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Compare the execution plans and see.

Comment: Please share the two execution plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan, please also share the table and index schemas

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say for sure without seeing an execution plan, but neither of these options are going to be performant, as you are querying the same table twice unnecessarily.

You could make this faster by using an `APPLY` and only sub-querying once

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1
      t2.depart,
      t2.arrival
    FROM table2 t2
    WHERE t1.tripId = t2.tripID
    ORDER BY t2.tripID DESC
) t2
WHERE t2.depart IS NOT NULL
  AND t2.arrival IS NULL;
```